# Задать событие методом

Tags: javascript

В интернете 100500 статей про то, как повесить событие клика.
При чём вешают она в атрибутах DOM элементов.
Я стараюсь следовать концепции "ненавязчивого" js.
Поэтому вопрос, как повесить событие например на ссылку.
Пробую вот так:

```
document.getElementById('bold').onclick = function(element){
    mainArea.focus();
    document.execCommand('bold', null, '');
    element.preventDefault();
};
```

Но что - то не выходит...
Посоветуйте.
Спасибо!

Comment: А что не получается: `document.execCommand` или `onclick`? Да, и не element, а event - для семантики. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<head>
<script>
function assign() {
    document.getElementById('to').onclick = function(e) {
        alert('Hi!');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="assign();">
    <a id="to" href="ya.ru">Click me</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

На jQuery

```
 <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">  
     </script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("a").click(function(event){
                 alert("We are staying here...");
                 event.preventDefault();
             });
         });
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <a href="http://jquery.com/">Click me</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Оберните ваш код $(document).ready() и поместите между тегами <head>...</head>